# Multi-Column Index Behavior in MySQL with Unused Index Column

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

Suppose I define the following index on a table in a MySQL database:

```
(col1, col2, col3)
```

I know that I get indexed search capabilities on `(col1)`, `(col1, col2)`, and `(col1, col2, col3)`.

Do I also get indexed search capabilities on `(col1, col3)`?

Comment: Yes, but only for the first-level match on `col1`. Since `col2` isn't being used, `col3` will force a table scan on whatever records have the matching `col1`. It's better than not having an index, but not as good as having full-coverage index.

Comment: So in other words, no, not on `(col1, col3)`. Only on `(col1)` (which will be used for part of the lookup on `(col1, col3)`).

Comment: that's another way of looking at it. the `col1` matches will be "fast" since the index can be used, but `col3` will have to scan the individual rows found by the `col1` match. so... partial table scan.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. An index is a B-tree. Before it can match the third column, it has to match the first two.

Comment: Just adding my €0.02: A partitial table scan can be a very cheap operation, if the majority of rows that match on `col1` live in the same or adjacent blocks. This has real-world repercussions, if there are only a few values of `col2` a.o.t. many values of `col1`

Comment: @EugenRieck Just what is a **partial** table scan?

Comment: @Blam A scan on a (most often continuous) subset of a table - when a high selectivity condition has reduced rows to a range of adjacent rows, the query plan might be to just scan through them a.o.t. using another index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summing up Marc B's answers from the comments:

You do not get full indexed search capabilities on `(col1, col3)` from the index `(col1, col2, col3)`; however, you will still get the benefits of a `(col1)` index with indexed search capabilities from the first level match on the `col1` portion of the query. A table scan would then be used on `col3`.

If it is necessary to have full indexed search capabilities on `(col1, col3)` (it may not be - see Eugen Rieck's comment), you would need a separate index on `(col1, col3)`.

Answer (score 1):

This is my experience with MSSQL so please test with MySQL

Consider a composite index on (col1, col2, col3)

You get an index seek on:
col1
col1 & col2
col1 & col2 & col3

On col2 and col3 you can get an index (not table) scan.
Since the index is smaller than the table this can help search times.
Some times this is a significant impact.

A search on col1 and col3 would (hopefully) be an index seek on col1 and an index scan on col3.

And note if the table is small you will just get some default plans
Need to load up with some data to test

Comment: MySQL is similar.  One clarification:  `SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM t WHERE col1 = 99 AND col3=88` do a "range scan" in the index without touching the "data".  But... `SELECT _somethingElse_ FROM t WHERE col1 = 99 AND col3=88` can't stay in the index.